# Change Karma configuration/files on the fly

Tags: config, karma-runner, on-the-fly

Is there a way to change configuration options for Karma once the Karma server has started?

e.g. if there is an additional file that Karma needs to load, how can you tell Karma to do that?

I'm using `autoWatch: false` and `singleRun: false`, triggering the runner through the `karma.runner.run` API after `karma.server.start` has been called from a different process with an initial config.

The `karma.runner.run` function accepts an `options` object as its first argument, but it seems to disregard the options entirely and stick with the original set of files.

Comment: The `files` property of the configuration is only used by the karma server to open up the right endpoints to get those files. AFAIK what you're looking for it's not that easy to achieve with the karma server running.

Comment: That's the conclusion I've come to after much digging, and don't see a way around it other than restarting the karma server. Thanks.